# Javascript LSP mode in Emacs (using typescript-language-server) uses inconsistent indentation between files

Tags: lsp-mode, javascript, lsp

On the first file I created, I had tabs set to 4 spaces and wasn't using the LSP yet. Then I enabled the LSP, and on all subsequently created files tabs are 2 spaces, yet on the original file, it keeps to 4 spaces. I'd prefer to have everything be 4 spaces, but I'd even be fine with everything being 2 spaces, as long as it's consistent. This inconsistent formatting is driving me insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lsp-mode` documentation](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/main-features/#formatting) states the following:

> settings that are controlled on `lsp-mode` level are indent
> size and whether the server should use tabs or spaces. Refer to
> `lsp--formatting-indent-alist` to find out what is the variable that is
> used for the current major mode.

Hence, [looking at `lsp--formatting-indent-alist`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/3143400be9dfc1335483838e24ae5e0f5705d420/lsp-mode.el#L5888), for the *major-mode* `typescript-mode` (for instance), set `typescript-indent-level` to the value you need/want, this way:

```el
(setq typescript-indent-level 2)
```

But this may differ depending on the actual setup you have (*major-mode*, package manager, etc). See the following `lsp-mode` discussions for additional examples:

- [How to pass config to language server to ask it to format a file with less spaces](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/discussions/3397).
- [Make lsp-format-buffer respect editorconfig](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/discussions/3308).

As another approach, try setting [lsp-enable-indentation](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/mode/#lsp-enable-indentation) to `nil`. This should disable `lsp-mode`-caused indentation fully.